# How can I post a message to an ActiveMQ queue using Powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, activemq-classic, powershell-2.0

I am trying to post a message ("mymessage") to an ActiveMQ queue ("myqueue"). In Powershell v3+, this is very straightforward using Invoke-WebRequest. Unfortunately, I am stuck with v2. To the best of my knowledge, this is the code in Powershell v3 that I need to replicate in v2:

```
$uri = "http://ACTIVEMQ-SERVER:8161/admin/sendMessage.action"

$r = Invoke-WebRequest http://ACTIVEMQ-SERVER:8161/admin/send.jsp -SessionVariable amq

$form = $r.Forms[0]

$form.fields["JMSDestination"] = "myqueue"
$form.fields["JMSPersistent"] = "true"
$form.fields["JMSText"] = "mymessage"

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -WebSession $amq -Method Post -Body $form.Fields
```

My current attempt looks like this:

```
$uri1 = [System.Uri]'http://ACTIVEMQ-SERVER:8161/admin/sendMessage.action'
$uri2 = [System.Uri]'http://ACTIVEMQ-SERVER:8161/admin/send.jsp'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('myusername',$password)

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri2)
$request.method = "GET"
$request.Credentials = $credential
```

As you can see, I haven't made much progress. I'm very new to Powershell, and especially the .NET aspect of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question was asked, but have you looked at [this](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-and-the-Windows-world-tp4702462p4703771.html)?

The `nms` or, .NET messaging API library [should work](https://github.com/ChugR/Apache.NMS.AMQP).